# When to use Mage::getSingleton() in my custom module/Ext

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, model, singleton

theoretically i know about `Mage::getSingleton()` & differences b/w
`Mage::getSingleton()` and `Mage::getModel()`

**but my question is that in my custom
module when to use `Mage::getSingleton()`**{Normally i used `Mage::getModel()` on lots of places}.

Please let me understand with example(if possible, please share a small custom modules having `Mage::getSingleton()`).

Answer (score 1):

As per My Knowledge On Magento.

Mage::getSingleton() creates an single object for one time.

Mage::getModel() creates an object every time.

Comment: Tnx! for the reply. I already mentioned that theoretically, I'm aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You know the difference and others already told you,

Its hard to give example, but I will try to give some scenario.

For example you are doing some work in some page and you need to load product id 1 in block class `x` .

now in same page you want to use same product object again in some other block class called `Y`, so at that time its preferred to use `singleton` over `getModel`

because product object already loaded in class `x` if you reload product object then it will impact your page performance.

> But if you want to load some other product id in block class `y` then
>   use `getModel` bcuz with the use of `singleton` you will get old
>   object

Hope you bit clear now

Comment: You are always welcome :) @wakarAhamad

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getModel($modelClass = '', $arguments = array())
{
    return self::getConfig()->getModelInstance($modelClass, $arguments);
}



public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

**GetModel**

> Mage::getModel() will always return a new Object for the given model:

**GetSingleton**

> Mage::getSingleton() will check whether the Object of the given model
>   already exists and return that if it does. If it doesn't exist, it
>   will create a new object of the given model and put in registry that
>   it already exists. Next call will not return a new object but the
>   existing one:

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I already went through it.i need some practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

Customer session model will be a great example of using `getSingleton`.

When you want to persist your data on that model object then you should use `getSingleton`.

It used to create model object at once and persist your data in memory .So that you can call `using getSingleton` same model into another class and then that object will have that data which was previously loaded.

**For eg** if you call `(using getSingleton)` a model inside controller and you are calling same model inside a block that is going to use on load of this controller then block will get same object that was initialize in controller.

But in case of `getModel` both will have separate object for same model.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getSingleton()` = Return the same instance.

`Mage::getModel()` = Return a new instance.

---

`Mage::getSingleton()` :

When you use `Mage::getSingleton()`, Magento search in the memory if the object needed is available :

1. If the object is available, It get it from that object every time and it will not create the object in every call.
2. If the object is not available, so it create it one time and it return it from that new object in every call.

---

`Mage::getModel()` :

Unlike the Singleton, getModel create a new object in every call.